# SUMIFS Function when using data validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to use the `sumifs` function to add together data based on 2 criteria.  However, 1 of the criteria is in a data drop down list.

I don't know whether this is causing my problem, but either way I can't get the sum to work.

Here's what I have so far

`=SUMIFS(Sheet1!Y16:Y35,Sheet1!I16:I35,$B$2,Sheet1!G16:H35,$A3)`

Any ideas?

Comment: You say you have a problem, but you do not write what it is the problem. What are the data, and the result you expect? [prepare a minimal set with such data]

Comment: Is there any way to attach a file as it would be a lot easier to explain

Comment: Do a simple case, and write, Columns Y has "1, 2, 3", Columns I, "2, 3, 4", B$2 is 3, and G .....  And the most important part: what it is your problem: what it is the expected value and what excel give it to you.

Comment: Column Sheet1!I16:I35 - contains job functions as a data validation list.  eg CNC P, CNC R etc.These are selected along with the job number in Column G

Column Sheet1!G16:H35 - contains job numbers eg. 3500, 3555, 3600.  These are random depending on what is manualy punched in.

Columns L/M/N/O/P/Q/R are days of the week titled Mon-Sun and hour are inputted.

Comment: In summary I want to input the job number then the job reference.  Then on another sheet total the job refernce hours next to the job number. for example: 

job 3500 - then the job references CNC R, CNC P with the hours underneath.

Comment: @MatthewRisidor you should edit your original question to contain the data / information you are posting in comments : people who may want to help won't trawl through comments to piece together the problem for you.